# input control not visible in jasper server, groovy expression might be the issue 

Tags: groovy, jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

```
(
$P{cal}.clear() ||
$P{cal}.set(Calendar.YEAR, $P{year_current})||
$P{cal}.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, $P{week_current}) ||
$P{cal}.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY) ||
$P{cal}.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4)
)
? null : $P{formatter}.format($P{cal}.getTime())
```

The above code calculates the start date from ‘week_current’ and ‘year_current’ input’s. The problem is that the code calculates the startDate in ireport but not in jasper server.

When I run the report on jasper server, the display mode (pop-up window) comes up blank without any input controls.

But when I change the above code to match one of your date calculations,the same report runs without any issues on jasper server i.e, the display mode (pop-up window) shows the defined input controls.

I would appreciate if you can let me know what is wrong on my date calculation expression which is preventing the input controls to appear on jasper server.

Comment: Your title mentions Groovy, but your problem description does not. If you change your parameter's default value to use Java (and change the report language to Java) does it work better?

Comment: When I change the report language to java from groovy in the ireport, the report throws an error saying that "the operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) void,void"

Comment: Yes, that's not a valid Java expression. But what happens if you change your parameter's default value to use Java?

Comment: can you please explain me in ireport 'how to change the parameter's default value to use Java'?

Comment: the above code is in the default value expression of the 'startDate' parameter.

Comment: I mean the above code is not a valid Java expression. Does the report work as expected when you use a valid Java expression instead?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to the problem, you need to pass the class `java.util.Calendar` as parameter:

http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2010/06/date-calculation-in-ireport/

Comment: I edited since the translation was simple and answer is ok, however you need to only pass answer in English